# Javascript array and variable not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to update tatol and orders value but it isn't updating please help.

```js
let total = 0;
let awaitingOrders = [];
invoice.orders.map(async(order, i) =>{
await db.collection("orders")
        .doc(order.id).get().then(orderDoc => {
      total += orderDoc.data().total; 
      awaitingOrder.push(order);
 }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });

console.log(total, awaitingOrders);
```

Total shows 0 and orders empty[] on console.log(). Why?

Comment: array.map does not return a Promise, so awaiting it makes no sense - in your code, `invoice.orders.map` will return an Array of Promises, perhaps you should wait for the array of Promises

Comment: `awaitingOrders` is an empty array that never gets used ... what about it?

Comment: If you need to modify the question, please do so. Comments do not replace question edits

Comment: in the edited code `awaitingOrder.push(order);` will run **after** `console.log(total, awaitingOrders);` - you need to wait for the promises returned by `invoice.orders.map`

Comment: modified it please check

Comment: I've suggested what you need to do ... twice now ... do you know about `Promise.all`?

Comment: _Please_ fix the indentation of your code and ensure that it is valid JavaScript. Currently,  it's missing a `)`

Comment: Loading data from Firestore (and pretty much any cloud API) is an asynchronous operation, since it takes time and the browser can't block the user while the data is being loaded. Any code that needs the data from Firestore needs to be *inside* the `then` callback block, so move the `console.log` there to see the correct values.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.map` generates an array of Promises, not an actual Promise. This is because your mapping function is an `async` function, which, effectively, returns a Promise for each element of `invoice.orders`.

To wait for all of those Promises to resolve, you need to use `Promise.all`.

For example:

```js
await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
```

Comment: if I'll remove async from mapping its showing same results

Comment: That's because the call to your database is inherently asynchronous. The reason that you're not getting a result is because you're not waiting for all of the operations to complete. If you remove the `async` (and, presumably, the associated `await`), then you're just changing the way that you're not waiting for the operations to complete.

Comment: Thankyou, the issue was solved. When i searched about this problem all were saying use promise but it wasn't clear where to use them. But With you detailed answer it was clear were to use it. 

Thankyou Dancrumb

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing orders to an array that doesn't exist because you spelled `awaitingOrders` wrong. It should say `awaitingOrders.push(order);`